# Implicit Questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, asking-questions, rules

Recently I have noticed a few cases of implicit questions.  The intended question is obvious, clear, and meets Stack Overflow requirements, but never explicitly stated.  Does a Stack Overflow post need an explicit question in this scenario?  Examples: [one of my own (before I added that edit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038641/fastest-inverse-square-root-on-iphone), and [one I came across while browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221817/do-different-things-if-for-tap-and-hold-gestures/21221925#21221925).

Comment: The second question you've linked to is entirely too broad; it only mandates a list of requirements as opposed to an actual *question*.  Your question is more concrete and answerable, as it boils down to, "How would one make proper use of this library?"

Comment: I think an explicit question is just a better question than one that has to be derived by the reader, hence by not explicitly stating your question you're leaving yourself open to more close/down votes - especially (and rightly so) if the question isn't clear from a single read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit questions are harder to read and should be avoided. However, if the implicit question is clear there is no need to close the question.

### Where the implicit question is clear

We have community editing for exactly this case, the question can easily be improved by making the implicit question explicit. Meaning the next person to read the question has to take less time over understanding the question

### Where the implicit question is not clear

This is the same as any other unclear question, close/flag under:

> **unclear what you're asking**
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's
> currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
> the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we need explicit questions.

Indeed it is often the case that the question is obvious, as in your first example. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822727/shannon-entropy-to-mutual-information) however, the real question seemed to be obvious. When I was reading its first revision I assumed that OP doesn't know exactly what set of equations should they use to calculate the desired quantity. Only after some discussions in the comments and edits it came out that a specific part of implementation is the real problem.

Things obvious to one person, can be surprising to someone else. They don't share the same context, in the broadest possible sense: context in solving this particular problem, context in terms of experience in a particular language/framework/library, context in terms of general problem-solving experience, and even linguistic and cultural context.

And regardless of this, this is a programming site. We should be as precise as possible. Natural language is not static-typed, which is a blessing and a curse. The fact that you can put a non-question into a question box can be sometimes convenient and useful, but should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO plenty of implicit questions don't need explicit statements. For example, is much gained with these explicit questions?:

- [Q ends with description of error message] What caused this error message and what should I do about it?
- [Q ends with "I'm stuck"] Any ideas how to proceed?
- [Q contains a summary of two alternative viewpoints] Who is correct, and why?

Comment: I would say the second two are both likely to be bad questions

Comment: What? A question where the asker explains what they're trying to achieve, spells out all the steps they've tried, and ends with "I'm stuck". Bad question? What is this site for?

Comment: "But I'm stuck" questions rarely explain what the problem is. "But then I get exception ABC" or I was expecting A but got B are far better.